# ServiceStack JsConfig.Init DateHandler to Local Time

Tags: c#, servicestack, json-deserialization

I'm using `JsConfig.Init(new Config {DateHandler = DateHandler.UnixTimeMs});` as was previously suggested and it's deserializing now but the times are all wrong due to it assuming UTC rather than local time.

How do I tell the deserializer to assume local time rather than UTC so my times are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix TimeStamps assumes UTC as per their definition - containing the number of seconds from Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC.

ServiceStack's default Date format uses [WCF Date Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb299886(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#from-javascript-literals-to-json) which contains a timeoffset that deserializes back into Local DateTime by default, why don't you stick to using the default?

Otherwise you can to convert the UTC DateTime to Local Time yourself with `.ToLocalTime()`

Comment: Maybe I should have worded my question better... is there a way to do the `.ToLocalTime()` during the deserialization rather than in a secondary operation like in the `[OnDeserialized]` method?